# How to draw table

Tags: html, tabular

Bear with me very new to html and css. I can draw normal table but not like this I have mentioned.

[image]

Comment: You are searching for `rowspan` and `colspan`. Find it in google.

Comment: I could find it but not able to make first columns two rows as 1 roe

Comment: Or just use this http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables# then study the code that is generated.

Comment: The down votes on this question are aggravating. Its as if people down vote because the question is too elementary, but I remember being new and asking some simple questions too. Lets be supportive of new people, even when they dont know enough to properly ask for what they want.

Comment: The downvotes are in place - We (Or at least, I) are not here to answer the basic questions over and over again, question such as this - It's about a basic and simple table that will be solved by reading a tutorial or two about HTML tables. If the OP  would have at leas try and post the code they tried.. But even this, is apparently too hard for them

Comment: It's a bad question that have tons of duplicateds. I didn't downvote, but them are meritory

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw you a bone since you say you're new.

```css
table, td {
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`rowspan`** & **`colspan`** properties in the  elements. For e.g

To draw a structure like this :

[image]

The code will be

```
<table class="" border=1px style="width: 40%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Puma</td>
    <td colspan="4">adidas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">superdry</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"> john player </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> biba </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> bagit </td>
    <td> jack&jones </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> peter england </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"> us polo </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Global desi </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> levis </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> spykar </td>
  </tr>
</table>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9TTK.png
```

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters called "rowspan" and "colspan" which give you what you are looking for.

http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span